# Convert ARIMA Model in R to Java Code (only the forecasting)

Tags: r, matlab

I would like to convert an ARIMA model developed in R using the `forecast` library to Java code. Note that I need to implement only the forecasting part. The fitting can be done in R itself. I am going to look at the `predict` function and translate it to Java code. I was just wondering if anyone else had been in a similar situation before and managed to successfully use a Java library for the same.

Along similar lines, and perhaps this is a more general question without a concrete answer; What is the best way to deal with situations where in model building can be done in Matlab/R but the prediction/forecasting needs to be done in Java/C++? Increasingly, I have been encountering such a situation over and over again. I guess you have to bite the bullet and write the code yourself and this is not generally as hard as writing the fitting/estimation yourself. Any advice on the topic would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [JRI](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/) or [RCaller](http://www.mhsatman.com/rcaller.php) to call R from Java and save yourself from re-inventing the wheel?